# VSTO Processing of large file upload and "Microsoft office Excel is waiting for another process to complete an OLE action"

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, dotnet-httpclient

My VSTO Addin needs to upload large files to our server, so in order to do that I've been using the `HttpClient.PostAsync`.
What happens is that for files that are fairly big (> 100Mb, but we need to handle files up to 5Gb) I get the "Microsoft office Excel is waiting for another process to complete an OLE action" error. 
It triggers a `TaskCanceledException` when it cannot do it in time.

I've tried the `Application.DisplayAlerts = false` solution, but while it doesn't trigger the modal warning us, the request still gets cancelled.

Here is the code that sends the request:

```
using (HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progressHandler))
using (MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);


    if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return null;

    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

My last resort would be to manually stream the file by reading it in chunks and sending them. However that kind of defeats the purpose of using HttpClient to stream the file upload.

I've searched for ways to increase or remove the delay before which the task gets cancelled but to no avail.